BertTokenizer vocab size vs length of tokenizer
I manually added vocabularies to a BertTokenizer. The original pre-trained BertTokenizer has 51,271 vocabs, and I added 209,902 vocabularies (therefore the total vocabulary size is 261,173) to the tokenizer using add_tokens(). I save the modified tokenizer with the save_pretrained() function to a local folder ./vocab, which the additional 209,902 tokens are saved in a file called added_tokens.json instead of merged with vocab.txt.
Then, I load the BertTokenizer with the following codes:
from transformers import BertTokenizer
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("./vocab")
print(len(tokenizer)) # 261173
print(tokenizer.vocab_size) # 51271
print(len(tokenizer.get_vocab())) # 261173

Question: How can I make the vocab_size identical to the total size of the vocabulary (i.e. 261173)?
The reason I am asking is that I am using MEGATRON framework to pre-train a model with this tokenizer, but after pre-training, it seems the newly added vocabularies are still not being used. The related MEGATRON script can be found here.
Should I manually replace the line with return len(self.tokenizer) or return len(self.tokenizer.get_vocab())?
